# Django 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, unicode

```
subjects_db = UTMESubjects.objects.values_list("List_of_Subjects", flat=True).order_by('id')[:]
        #return HttpResponse(subjects_db)
        for subjects in subjects_db: #inspects available subjects in db
            if subject in subjects:
                db_table = subject
                data = subject(
                        Questions = Question,
                        Options_1 = option1,
                        Options_2 = option2,
                        Options_3 = option3,
                        Options_4 = option4,
                        Options_5 = option4,
                        Answers = answer,
                        Difficulty_Level = difficulty_level,
                        Question_Year = question_year,
                        Diagram = "null",
                        Status = value,
                        )
                data.save()
```

I keep getting TypeError 'unicode' object is not callable. i try passing the value of subject as the table name when submitting to the database table. this is to allow multiple usage of code by different values of the variable subject.

Comment: hi cristiano2lopes. you are right. When i use the appropriate name in which the model was created, it works. but the problem is that i want to shorten the length of the code, as this code will be used for about 29 subjects belonging to 29 individual tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between the variable subject, which i suppose is a string, and the callable subject with which you are creating the model/object. The local one probably overriding the import of subject class.

I would use Subject as the model name as for python conventions. If it really needs be, change the local variable subject name or import subject class with other name.

```
import subject as subject_class
data = subject_class(
                    Questions = Question,
                    Options_1 = option1,
                    Options_2 = option2,
                    Options_3 = option3,
                    Options_4 = option4,
                    Options_5 = option4,
                    Answers = answer,
                    Difficulty_Level = difficulty_level,
                    Question_Year = question_year,
                    Diagram = "null",
                    Status = value,
                    )
```

Comment: @user2979827 That's a question of organising the code in such way. The unicode related question has nothing to do with that. You should probably rename the variable for a quick fix or use the appropriate CapWords case for classes in python. That way you will not have the clash anymore.